# Checking if url contains a number in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am making a middleware function in nodejs and express js framework and I want to check if the url contains a number in it or not just like this

/invoices/21 or /invoices/45

so I am trying to do something like this

```
 if (req.path.startsWith('/invoices/[^0-9]') {
    next();
  }
```

but i am getting error I am still not able to do so can anyone give hint.

Comment: you can't use regular expression like that

Comment: please tell me how to use regular expression in this situation

Comment: Try `req.path.match(/^\/invoices\/[^0-9]/`) and check the length of the result. Take care that your check also fails if a number is present but the path does not start with `/invoices`.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way is to check with `RegExp`

```
if(RegExp(/^\/invoices\/[0-9]/).test(req.path)){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a RegExp like that. startsWith only takes a string. This code creates a RegExp, and uses match to check if the string matches the RegExp.

```
if (req.path.match(new RegExp('/invoices/[^0-9]'))) { // create a regexp and check if it matches
    next();
}
```

Comment: Vikas is not testing for digits but for non-digits, and there a single non-digit is sufficient to make the test for a number fail.

Comment: it gives null if the match isn't made. your regexp is probably wrong. a null translates to a false in an if staments afaik.

Answer (score 0):

[startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) receives strings not regular expressions. You can use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) in this situation.

```
var str = '/invoices/120';
if (str.match(/^\/invoices\/\d+/)) { // return truly value
  next(); // gets executed
} 

var str = '/invoices/abc';
if (str.match(/^\/invoices\/\d+/)) { // return falsy value
  next();
}
```

You can check it out in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xxqfwcw/1/).

Comment: giving me null when I have ran

Comment: path.match(/\/invoices\/^\d+/)
null

> path = '/invoices/120'
'/invoices/120'
> path.match(/\/invoices\/^\d+/)
null
> 
> 
> path.match(/\/invoices\/[^0-9]/)
null
> path.match(/\/invoices\/[^0-9]/)
null

Comment: i don't understand. It shouldn't had to return null to '/invoices/120'. probably you're doing something else wrong

Comment: running this on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xxqfwcw/1/) and checking console shows this is working

Answer (score 0):

```
  const re = /^\/invoices(\/.*)?\/\d*\//
  if(re.test(req.originalUrl.toLowerCase())) {
    // include a number
  }

//'/invoices/kk/190/foo' will pass
//'/invoices/kk/190k/foo' won't pass
```

What version of express are you using? I can only access the path via req.originalUrl, no req.path.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying Naman's answer;

If you are checking for every single URL in a middleware which matches the condition, you could test that like so:

```js
if (/^\/invoices\/(\d)+/.test(req.originalUrl)) {
    // Do something when condition is true
}
```

This assumes you are now using the latest version of Express.